# Negative assertions in Supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, supertest

beginner to testing with Javascript.  I'm using Mocha but Louis wisely said nothing about this question is specific to Mocha.  I have a Node app that has some pages visible to an anonymous user and some that you shouldn't be able to see if you're not logged in.  So I have, as a very simple beginning,

```
describe('User Access', function(){
it('should allow anyone to access the help desk (about page)', function(done){
  request(host)
  .get('/')
  .expect(200, done);
}),
it('should allow anyone to access the contact page', function(done){
  request(host)
  .get('/contact')
  .expect(200, done);
}),
//initially we were expecting 404, we need anything BUT 200.
it('should NOT allow anonymous user to access the Training Material page', function(done){
  request(host)
  .get('/training')
  .expect(404, done);
}),
```

etc

This worked, initially.  HOWEVER, the developer has changed the non-available pages to 302 status, and redirects those to the root of the web app.  So, in order to give the dev flexibility as far as how he implements this restriction, I would like to change this to a negative assertion.  So, using the Mocha syntax, how do I "expect" the response to be anything BUT 200?

Comment: You know, ``request(...).get(...).expect(...);`` is not something inherent to Mocha. It looks like you are using supertest to provide this functionality. If I'm wrong, then please remove the tag I've added and edit your question to tell us where this functionality comes from.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs here](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest#expectfunctionres-) say that you can pass in a custom assertion function which is given the response object, returning a value from that function would mean the assertion fails, ie;

```
.expect(function(res){
    if(res.status == 200){
        return "we dont like 200!";
    }
})
```

Comment: Strange, this approach is not working. If I test for any specific response code (like the 302 it is now, or 404 or 200), the test comes back in a reasonable time (under 200 ms).  However doing this code exactly as written causes the code to time out.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be responding to the return value

Comment: Looks like you need to `throw`, not just return a string.